# Selenium: opening Firefox on a different display

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am using Selenium to do some tests on some webpages. I want all opened Firefox windows to start in a different X desktop (I am on display 0 and want them to start on display 1). I start the server with the command

```
DISPLAY=:1 java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar
```

but when I run my client, the server gets to the state

```
INFO - Launching Firefox...
```

but no further. When I switch to display 1, Firefox appears and everything works. However, I don't want to have to switch displays manually every time since I want my client script to be able to run as a cron job even when I'm not at the computer. Is there any way to fix this?